# pandas - using a column as a key for a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

One of the columns "**Status**" in my dataframe **dfUnderInterpretation** has values like "**OK**", "**Missing**" and "**New**".

Another variable **statusInterpretation** is a dict:
{'OK': 'INFO', 'New': 'WARN', 'Missing': 'ERROR' }

I want to create a new column '**Interpretation**' with dict values based on index in "**Status**" column of my dataframe.

This below of course wont work because **dfUnderInterpretation**['**Status**'] is a list.

***dfUnderInterpretation['Interpretation'] = statusInterpretation.get(dfUnderInterpretation['Status'], None)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use`apply` method:

```
dfUnderInterpretation['Status_Desc'] = dfUnderInterpretation['Status'].apply(lambda x: statusInterpretation.get(x))
```